# Django model predefined method override - how to do some math and auto-populate a third field?

Tags: django

EDIT: I got this working. This was the problem line of code(needed **self.**votes_total):

```
self.votes_total = self.votes_yes + self.votes_no
```

---

I'm hoping someone can guide me to the correct way to achieve this model override. My apologies if this a redundant question, fairly new at this.

Django version is 1.3.7

I'm working on a model and wish to auto populate a field with the sum of the other two fields (I actually want to do more math than that, but for now I just need a working concept). I have tried a few things but always seem to get the (1048, "Column 'xxxxxxx' cannot be null") error.

Here's a simple version

```
class Votes(models.Model):
    votes_yes = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    votes_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

    def save(self):
        votes_total = self.votes_yes + self.votes_no
        super(Votes, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which column is that?

```
(1048, "Column 'xxxxxxx' cannot be null")
```

That error means that one of your field is null or blank when `super(Votes, self).save()` is hit.

You don't show where you populate `votes_yes` and `votes_no` in your question. You probably forgot to populate one of these fields.

An easy "fix" is to simply default to `0`. That will avoid the error notifications; you still need to make sure that the `Votes` instance is correct though. A quick functional test is probably the best.

You can do:

```
votes_yes = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
votes_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
votes_total = models.IntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

---

Remark: I'd avoid to use a plural for a Model name.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that and I get a value of 0 for votes_total every time no matter the values of vote_yes and votes_no.

Comment: I just found the problem and got it working. Simple mistake, amazing what coming back the next day with a fresh head can do.



        **self**.votes_total = self.votes_yes + self.votes_no